# Creating multiple kendo grids

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a search criteria where there is a dropdownlist with 4 options and a text box for search text.. Now on click of search button, I need to show four different kendo grids but only one at a time based on which value is selected from dropdownlist..

So, what I am following is :

I have a div with below tag:

```
<div id='mygrid'> </div>
```

I want to keep only this div but I want to render 4 different grids here. This is because for one option of dropdown, we need to show grid which have 3 columns but for other options there are number of columns differentiating.

So in script tag:

```
<script>
```

Here i have created 4 different data sources which are working fine . on click of search button, I check the value of drop down, if it is blah blah, I call a function which contains different grid loads method.

So in this technique ,the new grid is not getting rendered in the same div.. Any ideas or suggestions that I can use to achieve this `</script>`

As I have posted the question from phone, the code is not showing.

Comment: Please provide some code that you have done. That will help us help you.

Comment: Do you really need 4 different grids or can you just destroy and rebuild the same grid with the different columns?

Comment: If you have the local data, you can do something like this: http://dojo.telerik.com/eKOxI. Or, if you have to request the data, we can customize the above example to handle it.

Comment: just destroy and rebuild the same grid with the different columns would be smart enough. Could you please provide any example for the same.